# Is this Python regex good enough for email address?

Tags: python, regex

I have been reviewing regex for Python3 to capture an email address. I have seen the doc on the popular regular-expressions website. And read the pydocs, SO answers, etc.

I would like to know if this regex is good enough to capture an email address or if I am missing something.

```
re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w.+-]+', some_string)
```

Comment: That depends on your definition of "good enough". Validating an email address with regex is hard to get right.

Comment: @BryanOakley most email addresses I have seen are numbers, letters, dash, period, plus, underscore. Not looking to validate a form, email field. But capture from scraping. The answer below said it would fail to capture ' and &. But I haven't seen such characters on an email address before. Good enough is the largest percentage of email addresses but not all.

Comment: Just be aware that "email addresses I've seen" is not the same as "all valid email addresses". But like I said earlier, it really depends on your definition of "good enough".

Comment: I have once seen a blog post of a guy who claimed to have written a comlete email address regex including IPv6, IDNs and stuff. It was several screen pages long.

Comment: @tomordonez Apostrophes are somewhat common in corporate email systems that use address formats like `FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME@example.com`, especially in conjunction with Irish patronymics like `O'Reilly` or `O'Sullivan`.

Comment: @duskwuff mm you are right. I didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 0):

No. This will fail to match email addresses with certain special characters in the local part. The most common characters this will miss are `'` and `&`, both of which are valid.